# Passing parameter as final in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

This might be a duplicate question.But could not find it in search
In java to mark a method parameter as constant we declare it as final whats the equivalent C# keyword?
Like

```
public void doSomeThing(final object myObject)
{
//print myobject
}
```

Comment: why dont you try with const keyword

Comment: @KahnS - because using that in a function parameter will not even compile.

Comment: If I were asked what C++ feature I miss the most in C#, it would be const methods and parameters.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible in C# - there is no way to mark a passed in parameter as a constant.

If you have a `const` that needs to be available to many functions, why not declare it with the right scoping (class scoping or global if needed)?

Comment: @Oded  The main intension of having final with method parameter is to declare it as non modifiable inside the method.It is not that you are making use of a constant value in it.This keyword helps in designing framework

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has so many upvotes. Final modifier in method parameter conveys that "the method will not change this parameter coming in". This has nothing to do with class or global scoping.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `readonly` keyword in C# but so far we can only apply it to fields, not locals or parameters.

Often in Java the `final` keyword is used habitually as a matter of style, to make it easier to close over values in anonymous inner classes. But that problem doesn't exist in C# as anonymous methods/lambdas can close over modifiable variables.

Also tools like Resharper can display mutated variables/parameters in a different colour, so you can see the "complications" in your method at a glance. I use it to make mutated names light up in bold green text or something like that!

This is not to say that C# itself wouldn't be improved by many more features like a widely applicable `readonly` to help with declared immutability. But if you have short methods and Resharper to highlight things for you, then you don't entirely need to manually declare things as final/readonly/const (depending on the language). The IDE tracks it for you.

This makes more sense: as Java coders have discovered, most "variables" are not variables at all. But if you have to declare this by adding `final` to everything, that's a lot of extra keyword noise in your code. It would make more sense for the default to be `final` and to have a keyword to make things `mutable`. This is how it works in F#.

Comment: key word noise.Pleasssssse.
As mentioned in my previous comment to oded.It helps in framework designing.Its the rule you define in ur abstract classes how it should behave,If its a little extra @ the benifit of good design effort so be it.

Comment: @Ravisha - I'm not saying "don't do it". It's essential in Java to allow closure from anonymous classes. I'm saying *if* you were designing a language today, maybe you'd pick the default to be the opposite, and have a `mutable` keyword instead. It's only commonsense to make the common case the default, and use a keyword to override it in the rarer cases.

Comment: Seems v both are on same line.I agree to have a keyword akin to mutable

Answer (score 3):

In C# 4.0 / Visual Studio 2010 with the Code Contracts add-on installed you can use Contract.Invariant in a ContractInvariantMethod attribute to check that a value is not modified during a method call.

Not quite the same thing but about as close as you'll get I think.

Answer (score 2):

there is no such thing in c#

Answer (score 1):

C# has a readonly keyword but it cannot be uset to local variables (class members only).
This means that there is no way to mark a metheod parameter constant.

I miss it too cause in my Java code almost every parameter and local variable is final (which is a good coding pattern I believe).

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, there's no such thing in C#.

If your intention is to **forbid the called method to change your object** (or know for sure it does not), your only option is to **pass a deep clone of your object**. - Not very elegant, but the only way possible to be sure.